# How does a MessageBox/ShowDialog() keep the program from continuing?

Tags: c#, wpf

When you show a `MessageBox` or another type of Dialog like a `OpenFileDialog` or even a window you made and called with `ShowDialog()` what is happening inside that method to keep the app from continuing while it waits for `DialogResult` to be set?

```
public static bool MyDialog.Show(string message) {
   //what happens here to keep the program from continuing?

   //Oh! DialogResult was finally set...
   return DialogResult;
}


private void OkButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    DialogResult = true
}
```

Its not like you can just put a while(true) loop and wait for the user to hit ok, so whats actually happening in the background?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/41769483/1086121 (and other documentation on `DispatcherFrame`)

Comment: DispatcherFrame is a c# thing and doesn't really answer the question.  
Modal windows are controlled through the underlying Win32 API that c# is calling.. In the case of DispatcherFrame.. that is what IT is calling.

Windows does this through a mechanism called a "Modal Window".
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_window
which gets invoked as a flag for the the underlying "CreateWindow" call.  Windows does the work..

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas I think there are two interpretations of the phrase "to keep the app from continuing while it waits for DialogResult to be set?". I assumed he was asking how the call to `Window.ShowDialog` didn't return until the dialog had been closed, yet dispatcher messages were still processed, the answer to which is absolutely "Dispatcher frames". I think you're answering the question "How come the user can only interact with the modal window, and not its parent", which is absolutely further down in the winapi

Comment: It is a `while` loop, which I call [message pump](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_loop_in_Microsoft_Windows).

Comment: The while loop IS a message pump! :^)  I didn't mean to diss anybody..
The message pump happens on non-modal windows too.. ALL windows have a pump.

Comment: Yep, there is literally a while loop for each window that is called a message pump. Which is a bit of an odd name and particularly so if you don't know what a windows message is. When you interact with windows - click or whatever - that generates a windows message. If you click a button then it's that message some bit of code listens for and drives what you ghink of as the click event. 
Maybe this explanation is clearer httpss://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/3f37a652-b558-4342-ade9-ad5ce68c9d01/why-does-showdialog-not-block-the-ui-thread-completely?forum=netfxbcl